# Preloading multiple images from network

Tags: flutter

As the title explains our app has a usecase where every single image from API response has to be pre-loaded from the network on app start and then all these photos should be available while offline. What could be the most performant way of achieving this with flutter?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using [cached_network_image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image) package.

> Widget now uses builders for the placeholder and error widget and uses
>   sqflite for cache management.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work really well when I had to resolve a big number of photos at the same time

Comment: Did you use it inside a FutureBuilder?

Comment: I created a helper method that used Future.wait to create a future that finishes when all network images resolve and called it from my redux thunk action when bootstraping app. But I'm almost sure that's not the correct way. CachedNetworkImageProvider isn't designed to work with large number of images at the same time